ASP.NET Core 8 Minimal API - Swagger with jwt
The authorization button is displayed, but if I paste a valid JWT token I got:

Error: Unauthorized
content-length: 0
date: Sun,12 May 2024 21:37:28 GMT
server: Kestrel
www-authenticate: Bearer

I don't know what's missing to make JWT auth work in Swagger:
builder.Services.AddSwaggerDocument(options => {
    options.PostProcess = document => {
        document.Info = new OpenApiInfo
        {
            Version = "v8",
            Title = "API",
            Description = "doc info",
            Contact = new OpenApiContact
            {
                Name = "Dúvidas e suporte",
                Email = "tech@email.com"
            }
        };
    };
    options.AddSecurity("bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
    {
        Name = "Authorization",
        In = OpenApiSecurityApiKeyLocation.Header,
        Type = OpenApiSecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
        Scheme = "bearer"        
    });
});

According to some search I should add this - but I couldn't find out how / where, because this method doesn't exist in NSwag.AspNetCore v14.0.7:
options.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
{
    {
        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Name = "Bearer",
            In = ParameterLocation.Header,
            Reference = new OpenApiReference
            {
                Id = "Bearer",
                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme
            }
        },
        new List<string>()
    }
});


If you replace OpenApiSecuritySchemeType.ApiKey with OpenApiSecuritySchemeType.Http, does this resolve the issue?

No, this don't work cause "http" means basic authentication.

Have you actually tried? Because "http" + "scheme: bearer" refers to Bearer authentication specifically. Basic auth would be "scheme: basic".

Also, does your code include options.OperationProcessors.Add(new AspNetCoreOperationSecurityScopeProcessor("bearer"));? See the Enable manual JWT token authentication example in NSwag docs.

@Helen answered bellow.

Found something that "worked":
builder.Services.AddSwaggerDocument(options => {
    options.PostProcess = document => {
        document.Info = new OpenApiInfo
        {
            Version = "v8",
            Title = "API",
            Description = "This doc...",
            Contact = new OpenApiContact
            {
                Name = "Questions",
                Email = "email@company.com"
            }
        };
    };
    options.DocumentProcessors.Add(new SecurityDefinitionAppender("JWT Token", new OpenApiSecurityScheme {
            Type = OpenApiSecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
            Description = "JWT Token",
            Name = "Authorization",
            In = OpenApiSecurityApiKeyLocation.Header
        })
    );
    options.OperationProcessors.Add(new OperationSecurityScopeProcessor("JWT Token"));
});

This way it correctly display the authorization page to put the auth string:
Authorization: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5c

But, as you can see if you don't explicit include the "bearer" in the beginning, it don't work.
I still searching for get it done correctly.
ps: the token string was shortened cause the token itself is not important

With OpenApiSecuritySchemeType.Http I have this:

With OpenApiSecuritySchemeType.ApiKey I have:

I believe there is something missing in the Swagger configuration, cause the API is working well, only through Swagger it's not working.

What about OpenApiSecuritySchemeType.Http with Scheme = "bearer"? Like so: https://gist.github.com/hkosova/9dee50b1fbdc9e87babbf7484638eb9c. It's supposed to change Basic into Bearer - unless there's a bug/limitation in NSwag.

But don't. It still display the basic authorization.

You shouldn't create an answer that is not an answer. Please remove the answer. You can include this information to your question.
